# Mypy error when an attribute is initialized to None and then used later

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Using `mypy==0.991` and Python `3.8`.

I have a class that initializes its attribute `kfp` to `None`. The user should run the `open` method first and then `produce`, and so at that point in time, `self.kfp` will not be `None`. Mypy however thinks that it is bad.

Thoughts on resolving this or adding an argument to `pyproject.toml` to ignore it?

Error:

```
error: "None" has no attribute "produce"  [attr-defined]
```

Code

```py
class Produce:
    """Class."""

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        """Init Doct String."""
        self.kfp = None

    def open(self) -> None:
        """Open Connection to Producer. Use with produce individually."""
        self.kfp = build()

    def produce(self) -> None:
        """Produce output."""
        self.kfp.produce()
```

Comment: I understand that `open()` should be called first, but what is stopping a user from using `produce()` first? How will they know that they need to use `open()` first? Shouldn't you check if `self.kfp` is **not** `None` and then do `self.kfp.produce()`. If it is `None`, throw an error or send an error log message.

Comment: Without a type hint, the type of `self.kfp` is inferred to be `None`, not `Optional[whatever you'll assign to it later]`.

Comment: This is also a sign that `Produce` is doing too many things. Perhaps `open` should return an object that has a `kfp` attribute, rather than having an attribute that may-or-may-not have such an attribute ready to use.

Comment: `t1 = Produce(); t2 = t1.open(); t2.produce()`. You can't prematurely call `t1.produce()` if `t1` doesn't *have* a `produce` method, and `t2` is ready to call `produce` out of the gate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For type checking, can I use decorators to check optional typed class attributes are defined to prevent None object has no attribute errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76052961/for-type-checking-can-i-use-decorators-to-check-optional-typed-class-attributes) @chepner it's your recent answer - don't you think these are very similar? Your comments suggest so...

Comment: @SUTerliakov Probably :) The technique is much the same, but I feel like the explanation of how any specific question (like this one) is solved by a "generic" presentation almost amounts to a full answer anyway.

Answer (score 3):

If you leave it up to the *user* to first call `open` (and you document your class' behavior accordingly), then *some* kind of runtime error in the `produce` method should make it transparently fail and admonish the user for violating the contract.

By writing an appropriate **type guard**, you will also satisfy a static type checker. Example:

```py
from typing import Optional


class KFP:
    def produce(self) -> None:
        ...


class Produce:
    kfp: Optional[KFP]

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.kfp = None

    def open(self) -> None:
        self.kfp = KFP()

    def produce(self) -> None:
        if self.kfp is None:
            raise RuntimeError("Must call `open` first!")
        self.kfp.produce()  # passes
```

The last line will no longer produce an error because the `is None`-check above it acts as a type guard that narrows the type of the `kfp` attribute after that check to the actual type (in this example `KFP`) that has a `produce` method.

Note also that you need to tell the type checker, that the type of `kfp` will be a union of `None` and `KFP` (I don't know your actual class). That is why I simply added a `kfp: Optional[KFP]` annotation in the class body.